# Does VPN encryption work on the provider's side? Or the client's side? What does Private Internet Access use?

Tags: ios, macos, encryption, vpn, openvpn

I'm using Private Internet Access as a VPN to encrypt my traffic, and they note they use "industry standard OpenVPN" which I understand is very good.

However, is this technology used on their server-side, or is it something that has to be used on my side as well? Do their Windows, Mac and iPhone client provide OpenVPN as well, or do I need to use TunnelBlick, or OpenVPN's iOS app, for instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The protocol used must be supported on both the server and client sides. PIA supports a wide range of protocols on their servers.

The PIA iOS app uses IPSec as the protocol, not OpenVPN. There are, however, OpenVPN apps available in the App Store that can be configured for use with PIA using the OpenVPN protocol:
[openvpn connect](https://www.privateinternetaccess.com/pages/client-support/ios-openvpn-connect)

Comment: What about the Mac app? And should I be worried about the use of IPSec?

Comment: The Mac PIA app does connect with OpenVPN. The only reason they claim they don't use OpenVPN on the iPhone app is a limitation on who Apple allows to implement custom VPN protocols, i.e. those outside of the ones supported by Apple. As for the use of IPSec...you'll get varying responses depending on whom you ask. The following link outlines the pros and cons: https://www.ivpn.net/pptp-vs-l2tp-vs-openvpn